# ADODB Stream not clearing cache when set to Nothing

Tags: vba, ms-access, stream, adodb

Hoping someone can help. I am trying to download both MS Access databases and Excel files via URL link, but if the file updates, my download script does not update the stream. The cache is not clearing when the variable is set to nothing. The next time I try to run the code, the original file downloads instead of the updated file.

I have tried adding "set to nothing" in multiple places, but I think my problem, as I found in a similar post here is that I am not more specific with my declaration of the object variables. I'm not very experienced with this aspect of VBA.

```
Dim sFo as string
Dim oStrm As Object
Dim HttpReq As Object
Dim nwLBUDir As String

sFo = "http://10.38.111.342/Shared_Docs//Docs/Locfile.mdb"
nwLBUDir = Application.CurrentProject.Path

Set HttpReq = CreateObject("microsoft.XMLHTTP")
    HttpReq.Open "GET", sFo, False
    HttpReq.send

    sFo = HttpReq.responseBody
    If HttpReq.Status = 200 Then
        Set oStrm = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        oStrm.Open
        oStrm.Type = 1
        oStrm.Write HttpReq.responseBody
        oStrm.SaveToFile nwLBUDir & "\" & "Locfile.mdb", 2
        oStrm.Close
    End If
    Set oStrm = Nothing
```

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could point out what I am failing to do to get the variable to set to nothing. Thank you ahead of time. :)

Comment: Well, I've been playing around with it more, and it seems to be some sort of slowing down of my system. If I wait several minutes, the file updates correctly. I'm running Win 10 on a very new system....How can I check to see if the memory has correctly been cleared and how long that takes (if that's even possible)?

Comment: Have you tried `With CreateObject("microsoft.XMLHTTP") ... End With`?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I haven't tried that. Do you have an example of how I might make that work or a link for some instruction?